# Android ZBar QR Code Scanner - How to read every QR Code

Tags: android, zbar

I currently implemented ZBar QR Code Scanner Library into my own app. But, so far, I am just able to read a QR Code that leads to a website. What should I do if I want to scan a QR Code that leads you to dial a phone number or text messages? How do I make my app read any QR Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the QR code should be irrelevant -- it's just text. It might happen to contain a URL, but that doesn't change the format of the QR code.

```
int result = imageScanner.scanImage(image);

// Nonzero means a result was found
if (result != 0) {

    // Typical only one symbol unless multiple codes were found
    // in the scanned image
    for (Symbol symbol : imageScanner.getResults()) {

        // .getData() gives the string content of the QR code
        String qrCodeContent = symbol.getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. But what if the QR Code is suppose to take you to another application on your device. How do I make my app to do that? So far it only takes me to a website. When I scan a QR code that is suppose to take me to my contacts, I get a message saying "Unfortunately, your app, has stopped". I don't know if I need to use intent for other cases. So far I am using this code: Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT)));
    startActivity(browserIntent);

Comment: That's an entirely too broad question. Scanning a QR code is the process of decoding an image into text. What you do with that text depends on: 1) the content of that text, 2) what you want to do with the text based on the content. Those are deserving of separate questions (although I imagine most answers are a quick Google search away).

Comment: Ok. Yes I'll definitely research more about this topic. Thank you so much!